# No response from "turtlebot" pc

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i have been following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Network%20Configuration

But after editing my .bashrc according to the tutorial on both pcs like this:

Desktop PC:

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.150:11311

export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.107

Laptop PC:

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.150

I am not able to get any sort of communication between the two PCs. For instance, when i run roscore from the laptop (192.168.1.150) and rostopic list from my desktop (192.168.1.107), my desktop PC has no response at all. The same the other way around (even if i change the .bashrc ofc). I am using vmware on both PCs with a bridged connection that "replicates host pc connection", dont know if that has anything to do with it.
I can ping the PCs with each other.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249432/no-response-from-%22turtlebot%22-pc/) by [axel0143](https://answers.ros.org/users/28722/axel0143/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry I meant to say ROS_IP not ROS_HOSTNAME -

Set  **ROS_IP**=192.168.1.150 on the Desktop PC and on Laptop

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2016-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [axel0143](https://answers.ros.org/users/28722/axel0143/) on 2016-12-06**:
With:

Desktop PC:

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.150:11311

export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.150

Laptop PC:

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.150

Rostopic list from the laptop gives "unable to communicate with master" and desktop gives no response.

**Comment by [axel0143](https://answers.ros.org/users/28722/axel0143/) on 2016-12-06**:
Desktop gives no response with those .bashrc settings no matter whether i run rostopic list or roscore. And thank you for responding!